# Is this fancy iOS login dialog a standard component?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, dialog, modal-dialog

The modal dialog for adding iCloud accounts on iOS 7 is shown below. Is this type of dialog a standard iOS component of some kind? Specific elements of interest are the navigation bar and title on top that seem well integrated with the general iOS UI. I'm obviously looking to avoid reinventing the wheel for my own generic login dialog.

[image: iCloud login dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a standard view that's part of the SDK, but it's easy enough to replicate using a grouped UITableView and a UITableViewCell subclass that contains a UILabel and UITextField for the Apple ID and Password cells.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is nothing built-in here. You need to create your own.